# Отправка сообщения бот telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, requests

импортировал библиотеку `requests`. 
через нее отправил https запрос:

```
r = requests.get(f'{main_url}/sendmessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text=hello')
```

выдает `ошибку 403` и не отправляет сообщение

Comment: Не забыл впн включить?

Comment: А тут нигде не нужен апи-токен?

Comment: впн включил, апи токен есть в main_url

Answer (score 3):

а почему get?

```
tlgrm_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage'
proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://LOGIN:PASS@IP:1080'}

msg = {'chat_id': 123, 'text': 'привет'}  # если отправка в группу, то id с минусом: -123
requests.post(tlgrm_url, data=msg, proxies=proxy)
```